# Location of stored offline data for cartopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, cartopy

Where is offline data stored in cartopy? Is it stored in the data folder under site-packages? Is there any way to trigger the downloading of all available data? I would like to copy this over to a Linux machine that is not connected to the internet. I'm currently working from a Windows machine that is connected to the internet, so I'm hoping to download the data from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at the config docs in http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/cartopy.html. Essentially, the data is downloaded to the `data_dir` item in that config. For me that looks like:

```
>>> import cartopy.config        
>>> cartopy.config['data_dir']
'/home/pelson/.local/share/cartopy'
```

Of course, that can be configured to wherever you like.
Because I also deploy cartopy to my organisation, we also configure cartopy to have centrally stored data. This is put in a location determined by the `pre_existing_data_dir` config item.

Finally, to batch download all of the data (which is several GB), there is a script in the cartopy source at [tools/feature_download.py](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/tools/feature_download.py). Running it to download all of the data is simply:

```
$> python tools/feature_download.py
```

Full help is available:

```
$> python tools/feature_download.py --help
usage: feature_download.py [-h] [--output OUTPUT] [--dry-run] [--ignore-repo-data] GROUP_NAME [GROUP_NAME ...]

Download feature datasets.

positional arguments:
  GROUP_NAME            Feature group name: cultural-extra, cultural, gshhs, physical

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --output OUTPUT, -o OUTPUT
                        save datasets in the specified directory (default: user cache directory)
  --dry-run             just print the URLs to download
  --ignore-repo-data    ignore existing repo data when downloading
```

Comment: In Cartopy 0.20.0 `feature_download.py` was renamed to `cartopy_feature_download.py` and should be added to the path, so you can now just call it as `cartopy_feature_download.py` from the command line