# Trying to use Cartopy at work behind a firewall and proxy

Tags: cartopy

I am trying to use Cartopy at my office to plot flight patterns over a world map. I understand Cartopy needs to access http://naciscdn.org/naturalearth in order to receive the proper maps.

My firewall and proxy seem to prevent this. When I run a script (even the example ones) I receive the following message: .

My question: is there a way to obtain these maps locally and change the path Cartopy takes to locate the map images to plot over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Cartopy in exactly this situation, and the downloading mechanism works fine behind a firewall when I have my `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` set appropriately.

If you do want to download all of the data in advance, there was a similar question asked recently: [Location of stored offline data for cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365410/location-of-stored-offline-data-for-cartopy).

If you wanted to dig deeper, the underlying downloading happens using Python's urlopen and can be found [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/lib/cartopy/io/__init__.py#L33-L36).

HTH