# Use Cartopy Maps Offline

Tags: offline, cartopy

I am trying to plot maps using Cartopy offline. I've found this post:
[Location of stored offline data for cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365410/location-of-stored-offline-data-for-cartopy)
However, after changing `cartopy.config['data_dir']` to `'C:/...'` where the downloaded files are located, when I try to draw coastlines, it still wants to download the map.

```
cartopy.config['data_dir'] = '.../CartopyMaps'
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
```

The console says :

```
Downloading: 
http://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip
```

However, I have `ne_110m_coastline` dbf, shp, and shx files in `.../CartopyMaps/shapefiles/natural_earth/physical/`

Why does Cartopy not see my local maps and how can I help it?

Comment: Did anyone ever get a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.  Cartopy insists on downloading maps even though I have them in the prescribed data_dir

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "pre_existing_data_dir" path instead of the "data_dir".

```
from os.path import expanduser
import cartopy
cartopy.config['pre_existing_data_dir'] = expanduser('~/cartopy-data/')
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the similar problem and was confused for quite a while. after i downloaded the whole offline dataset and put them in the right dir, after runing the code

```
...
states = NaturalEarthFeature(category="cultural", scale="50m",
                             facecolor="none",
                             name="admin_1_states_provinces_shp")
...
```

the console still says:

```
Downloading: 
...50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp.zip
```

however, i found there is a slight difference between the file  `ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines.shp` i downloaded and the file `ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp.zip` cartopy tries to acquire ('_shp').

therefore i changed the command into this and it worked:

```
states = NaturalEarthFeature(category="cultural", scale="50m",
                             facecolor="none",
                             name="admin_1_states_provinces")
```

Answer (score 0):

I shared a step by step solution here:
https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/using-geoviews-tile-sources-offline/4859/5

TLDR:

```
import cartopy
import geoviews as gv
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

cartopy.config["pre_existing_data_dir"] = "/Users/ahuang/.cartopy/cartopy"
print(cartopy.config)

gv.extension("bokeh")

coastline = gv.feature.coastline()
borders = gv.feature.borders()
world = (coastline * borders).opts(global_extent=True)

gv.save(world, "world.html", resources=INLINE)
```